# Travis-ci - build:error - "Merge branch 'master' of github.com:userName/projectName"

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

I did just connect my new angular.js github project to Travis CI.
My last Job status is "Passed".
My last Build status is "Errored" (and so is my build button... :-)
The build "Message" is: "Merge branch 'master' of github.com:userName/projectName".
I don't understand if this is the cause of the "errored" status, and what should I do to correct it...

This is my last job log: https://travis-ci.org/marcolino/paypalButton/builds/22527275

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is unreleated to the `message`, which is just the commit message. If you look at the logs you will see that npm cannot find a version of grunt-protractor-runner that matches the version specified. This is because your `package.json` is using the new ^ syntax, which was introduced in a recent version of npm, hence why your installation works on node v0.10 but not v0.8. You can either change this ^ to a ~ or remove node v0.8 from your `.travis.yml`

Comment: Thanks! I have some other errors yet, but now I know how to address them, and (hopefully) to solve them... :-)